# Solving equations that involve the modulus

Tags: functions

Im often stuck on these types of equations, usually because I don't know which solutions to select as the intersection points. E.g. this question:

$ 2|x|= 3 + 2x -x^2 $

To solve this the method I used was to:

1. Draw the graph.
2. First, because taking the mod out means x can be positive or negative I solve two equations; $ -2x = 3 + 2x - x^2 $ and $ 2x = 3 + 2x - x^2 $ in doing so I get $4$ solutions:

From the first equation; $x= \sqrt{3} \text{ or} -\sqrt{3}$; $x= 2 \pm \sqrt{7} $

Now from this point I do one out of two things

1. I look at the graph I drew and compare where it looks like the points match with my solution (I get $-\sqrt{3}$ and $2+\sqrt{7}$ as my $x$ values for intersection ). Which was not correct
2. I sub all four solutions back into the original equation, but this again does not leave me with the answer

The answer for the equation is $x= \sqrt{3}$ and $2-\sqrt{7}$

I often make mistakes like this, but on the other hand it sometimes works. I was wondering 1. what I have done wrong 2. How to solve this equation

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have to consider two cases:
$$x\geq 0$$ then we get $$2x=3+2x-x^2$$
$$x<0$$ then we have to solve: $$-2x=3+2x-x^2$$
The solution is given by $$x=\sqrt{3}$$ or $$x=2-\sqrt{7}$$

Comment: This makes so much sense. So does  this  mean in every case so  you take the positive value for the mod then x ≥ 0 and if you take the negative mod then <0

Comment: Also, I was wondering if you had a modulus on both sides, and you were to take the negative of one side and the positive of one side, what would you do then ?

Comment: Please give an example for your question.

Comment: $2-|x+1| = |4x -3|$

Comment: Now you will get the cases: $$x\geq \frac{3}{4}$$,$$-1\le x<\frac{3}{4}$$ and $$x<-1$$

Comment: Why do you have $−1≤<3\4$  ? I understand the first and last one but not the middle?

Comment: So we get $$2=-(4x-3)+x+1$$

Comment: I was wondering how you would derive the inequality